# "She do not look like"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I have heard this phrase in "True Detective". What's the background? 
(It was used by police detective, 2nd episode, the dialog in a car.)

update:

Because of the discussion, I found that scene and have listened it exactly with headphones. The exact phrase (32:46) - "She do not look like"

The meaning of the question remains. Using 3rd person + "do".

Comment: I've seen all eight episodes and can't recall that sentence. I think I would have remembered.

Comment: You are asking us what the *background* is??? If they truly used this *phrase* as you call it, you will have to provide background so we can tell you the reason or meaning behind this. flagged as too broad. Equal how: from a grammatical viewpoint this is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: It seems like it's just a dialectical variation of _She doesn't like (something)_.

Comment: I mean an english background, of course. Btw., while googling I noticed that Justin Bieber uses this sentence in a song. I do not try to find the relationship. Just saying. I repeated the scene to make me believe.

Comment: Google finds [a total of 24 instances of that text](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E2%80%9CShe+do+not+likes%22&oq=%E2%80%9CShe+do+not+likes%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10539857j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%E2%80%9CShe+do+not+likes%22&start=20) (one of which is this question, obviously). All the rest look like non-native speakers to me. @Barmar: - no way is it a "dialectal variant". Voting to close as "Unclear".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was thinking of dialects like Black English that conjugate differently, like "She don't like". Also "cute" phrases like "Me no likey".

Comment: @Barmar: I expect it's just a mishearing, only not so obvious as [this one earlier today](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223830/a-new-use-for-the-word-alibi), so perhaps we need a link to an audio source. Not that this would make it On Topic - just *answerable*.

Comment: It also could just be an individual ideosyncracy. The characters on True Detective were kind of weird.